# Reboot to Windows 10 changes time

Tags: time

Using GRUB to dual boot between elementary OS and Windows 10. After using elementary and rebooting to Windows 10 the time is mysteriously 4 hours off. Just started happening a few months ago. So, every time I reboot to Windows 10 after using elementary I have to reset the time in Windows. Reboot to elementary after using Windows and the time doesn't change. Anyone else seeing this happen to them?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/250643/system-time-is-wrong-in-windows-7-after-dual-booting-ubuntu there is the answer on your question :)

Comment: Yes I experienced the same problem. Even after changing the time manually I still have the same result. At this point I am not too much troubled looking for a solution for a system that doesn't really foresees any other operating system apart from that only one. I would suggest not to worry about this strangeness that inhabits Windows as platform since its origins

Answer (score 1):

As user [Amphyby](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/3069/amphyby) commented, this is a known situation when you install a distro in dual boot configuration with Windows.

Basically what is happening is that Windows reads the computer time as local time, while elementary reads it as [UTC.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

Easiest way to solve it is to just run this command in the terminal to set elementary to also read time as local:

> timedatectl set-local-rtc 1

Answer (score 0):

check the windows time zone if it is matched with Linux location you set.
windows has this set time automatically feature .
and maybe your linux distro is setting the time based on location too